# Facebook app on Google app engine (php Graph api)

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have installed Quarcus using java in google app engine and php is working fine.

Now i am really interested to use facebook in app engine.But i am struck in middle.

I got the access token successfully, I used below code to get an user ID

```
$url =  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;
 $response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $url;
```

but i am getting below error

**Warning: /me cannot be read [file_get_contents] https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=sdfsdfsft0GhbgkL54nwRjlF8oZCkdgFhb0b2M45JfVIZBX9PMZCvgkTPmjDawHSFt7KiZA67PVRws2OG3x6R5tKksdfsdfsf**

But when i access the above url in browser its working fine.Any help please.

p.s : heard that curl dont work on google app engine..is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application haven't direct access to internet, you must use urlfetch.

You must find way to run java functions from php and use it.

For Java you can see documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview

Low-level: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary